# Reorder dataframe rows by custom ordering rule

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of states + DC. They should be ordered by name, but with `DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA` coming first. Not-in-place method-chaining operations are preferred.

The following works great, and is in the chaining style I prefer. But it seems way too complicated for such a simple operation. Is it possible to do this in a cleaner way?

I start with

```
>>> states = pd.DataFrame({
 'state_name': ['ALABAMA', 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', 'WYOMING',], 
 'population': [1000, 2000, 3000]
 })


>>> states
   population            state_name
0        1000               ALABAMA
1        2000  DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA
2        3000               WYOMING
```

and do

```
>>> (
     states
    .assign(state_name = lambda x: x.state_name.astype('category', ordered=True))
    .assign(state_name = lambda x:x.state_name.cat.reorder_categories(
        ['DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA']
        +  x.state_name.cat.categories.drop('DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA').tolist())
    )
    .sort_values('state_name')
)
```

to get

```
   population            state_name
1        2000  DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA
0        1000               ALABAMA
2        3000               WYOMING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do:

- Create a boolean series `states.state_name.ne('DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA')`.  This will be `False` for `'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA'` and `True` for everything else.
- If we sort this boolean series, the `False` comes first and all the `True` come after.  If we use a stable sort, then those `True` values will stay in the same order.  `mergesort` is a stable sort.
- However, we need to use `iloc` with `argsort` to get the permutation that represents that sort.

Lot of words to describe this:

```
states.iloc[states.state_name.ne('DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA').argsort(kind='mergesort')]

   population            state_name
1        2000  DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA
0        1000               ALABAMA
2        3000               WYOMING
```

---

You could also add a column to use in `sort_values`

```
states.eval(
    'dc = state_name != "DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA"', inplace=False
).sort_values('dc', kind='mergesort').drop('dc', 1)

   population            state_name
1        2000  DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA
0        1000               ALABAMA
2        3000               WYOMING
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the name `states` inside of `iloc`, to ease chaining?